# Looking for a game system to handle non-human PCs in a modern setting (Not horror)

Tags: game-recommendation, modern

I've got (what I think are) some great ideas for an RPG scenario to run at the local 'Con next year, but none of the resources I have on hand seem to fit the story idea. Hoping to find a system that would work for the following:

- The PCs will be playing non-humans (specifically time-displaced intelligent dinosaurs) in a modern setting with the primary objective of finding a way back home and not getting captured.
- This will be a one-shot adventure restricted to a 4-hour timeslot, so mechanics should be quick to explain and not bog the adventure down.
- I am **not** anticipating a combat-heavy adventure. Focus will be more on problem solving/roleplay and getting into/out of absurd situations.
- Ideally, the materials needed would all be found in one book. (I don't want to make a massive investment for a once-off if I don't have to!)

Hopefully this is enough to give an idea of the type of game I'm looking for, but feel free to ask for clarifications in the comments.

Comment: This could be done with hundreds of games - try to narrow down more of what you'd like out of a system to support this. What do you "have on hand" and why doesn't it fit?  What would make GURPS, FATE, or Savage Worlds a better answer than the other?